# is there any way to auto stop spooler in oracle I close the sqlplus accidentally

Tags: oracle, spool

If I accidentally Close the sqlplus console of Oracle How I can create some trigger in order to stop the spooling and save the complete data untill that moment in the mentioned spool file.

Comment: If you have a trigger like that, and then you close the SQL\*Plus console, how will the trigger know that you **accidentally** closed it (and not on purpose)?

Comment: So can we have a trigger to stop spooling whenever the console closes (on purpose  or intentionally).

Comment: Huh??  there is no such thing.

Comment: This is possible if you do not run sqlplus directly, but through a program that calls sqlplus. And the sqlplus output is written to a file, without using spool on. for example here https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_all_sql_dir.ps1.